# Downloading apk with specific option

Tags: android, apk

I am just wondering if there is possibility to make clients to download apk with specific options for them?
eg.
Someone downloads apk from **www.mysite.something/app_with_black_metal_design** and recives app with black metal design and a couple of black metal mp3 samples inside. 
And another scenario:
Someone downloads THE SAME apk (I mean functionality) from **mysite.something/app_with_pop_design** and recives app with pop (pink) design and a couple of pop mp3 samples inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can enumerate and pre-generate all the choices, ideally using scripts to make them all.

Or you can dynamically generate (and sign!) them on request by having your web server launch various Android build tools (ant, maven, etc) taking inputs and driving the low level android build tools.  You might even be able to simply combine prebuilt resource components before the zip stage (apk's are zip files) and sign.

However, dynamic generation will have some issues:

- It may take longer than the client downloader wants to wait, especially if it becomes popular, so you may need a way to email the result or something like that.
- You'll have to put the signing certificate on the web server, which runs the risk that if someone breaks into your server and steals it, they can publish malicious updates that would seem to be from you.

Also, be aware that many users will not be comfortable configuring their devices to install applications other than through an official channel such as the Android market or a well known alternative (Amazon or Nook store, etc) perhaps pre-whitelisted by their device vendor.

Comment: so how to make zip with sample.mp3 + apk that will know what to do with this mp3?

Comment: An apk *is* a zip file.  If the code can always refer to the mp3 by the same name, you can just generate the apk with one version, then use a zip program to replace it and strip the signature file.  Run zip align and run jar signer again.  Instructions all over the place (you are basically re-skinning an app, albeit your own), you can Google for the details yourself as readily as I can.